# DOM Traversal with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this markup

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div id="carousel-race-track">
    <%= image_tag 'race_track/track_curved.jpg', data: { engine: 'Sports'}  %>
    <%= image_tag 'race_track/track_hills.jpg', data: { engine: 'Hills'}  %>
    <%= image_tag 'race_track/track_rough.jpg', data: { engine: 'Rough'}  %>
    <%= image_tag 'race_track/track_straight.jpg', data: { engine: 'Straight'}  %>
  </div>
  <p class="lead"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-info select">Select</a></p>
</div>
```

When I click on the `.select` for example, how would I traverse the DOM to get to the div `#carousel-race-track`?

I'm going to have multiple carousels so will wildcard the id search, prefixed with `carousel-`.

I'm trying to say something like this:

```
$('.select').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var carousel = $(this).closest("[id^='carousel-']");
  $(carousel).cycle('pause');
});
```

Is `closest` the wrong method here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest finds the closest parent that matches the selector. You want to use parent to get to .lead and then prev which finds the previous sibling that matches the selector.

```
$('.select').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var carousel = $(this).parent().prev("[id^='carousel-']");
  $(carousel).cycle('pause');
});
```

Or you could do this:

```
var carousel = $(this).closest('.col-md-3').find("[id^='carousel-']");
```

This finds closest .col-md-3 parent then finds the carousel inside it.

Comment: @Richlewis no problem! =]

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent().siblings();` should do the job.

If you have different siblings you have to specify the one you're interested on with a selector.

Keep in mind that returns a `jQuery` object, so you have directly append any `jQuery` method to it:

```
carousel.cycle('pause');
```

Comment: .select is not a sibling of carousel

Comment: Ye, just noticed now. Formatting on SO mobile it's not the best